# Single word for the phrase "to give more than you take"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word or a formal phrase that means  "to give more than you take"? If not in English, then in Latin?

Comment: This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Single word requests in particular are required to have an example sentence where the word would be used. Primarily to make clear what kind of word you are looking for.

Comment: Someone who gives more than they take is *selfish*.

Comment: @JonLarby *selfless*, surely?

Comment: @Spagirl  - indeed, what's the word for *total reading failure*?!

Comment: @JonLarby :D I call 'em brain-farts or senior moments when they happen to me.

Comment: @JonLarby You are not alone. I did the same thing, except that I wrote a proper answer with reference links then had to delete it immediately!

Answer (score 1):

**Altruism** seems to fit, although there's little context here to give a more focussed answer.